# Notification of alert dialog is not displaying on MFC application using CMFCDesktopAlertWnd class

Tags: c++, mfc

I've got project using TCP/IP protocol to send and receive data, and at the same time,

I will show an alert dialog on bottom-left of screen to know that if there any data is being sent

I want to build it into a fuction and run it on thread separately. However after sending data, I haven't got any notification and there is not also any error.

Does anyone help you solve this problem. Many thanks.

Here is my code:

```
UINT JobManager::JobInfoAlert(LPVOID pParam)
{
THREADSTRUCT*   ts = (THREADSTRUCT*)pParam;
WSADATA wsData;
WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

int wsOk = WSAStartup(ver, &wsData);
if (wsOk != 0)
{
    AfxMessageBox(L"Can't Initialize winsock! Quitting");
    return 1;
}

// Create a socket
SOCKET listening = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (listening == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    AfxMessageBox(L"Can't create a socket! Quitting");
    return 1;
}

// Bind the ip address and port to a socket
sockaddr_in hint;
hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
hint.sin_port = htons(54000);
hint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY; // Could also use inet_pton .... 

bind(listening, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));

// Tell Winsock the socket is for listening 
listen(listening, SOMAXCONN);

// Wait for a connection
sockaddr_in client;
int clientSize = sizeof(client);

SOCKET clientSocket = accept(listening, (sockaddr*)&client, &clientSize);

char host[NI_MAXHOST];      // Client's remote name
char service[NI_MAXSERV];   // Service (i.e. port) the client is connect on

ZeroMemory(host, NI_MAXHOST); // same as memset(host, 0, NI_MAXHOST);
ZeroMemory(service, NI_MAXSERV);

if (getnameinfo((sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(client), host, NI_MAXHOST, service, NI_MAXSERV, 0) == 0)
{
    //cout << host << " connected on port " << service << endl;
}
else
{
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, host, NI_MAXHOST);
    //cout << host << " connected on port " <<
    //ntohs(client.sin_port) << endl;
}

// Close listening socket
closesocket(listening);

// While loop: accept and echo message back to client
char buf[4096];
while (true)
{
    ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);

    // Wait for client to send data
    int bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, buf, 4096, 0);
    if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(L"Error in recv(). Quitting");
        break;
    }

    if (bytesReceived == 0)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(L"Client disconnected");
        break;
    }

    CMFCDesktopAlertWnd* pPopup = new CMFCDesktopAlertWnd;
    int m_nAnimation = 2;
    int m_nAnimationSpeed = 30;
    int m_nTransparency = 180;
    bool m_bSmallCaption = false;
    bool m_bAutoClose = false;
    int m_nAutoCloseTime = 3;
    pPopup->SetAnimationType((CMFCPopupMenu::ANIMATION_TYPE) m_nAnimation);
    pPopup->SetAnimationSpeed(m_nAnimationSpeed);
    pPopup->SetTransparency((BYTE)m_nTransparency);
    pPopup->SetSmallCaption(m_bSmallCaption);
    pPopup->SetAutoCloseTime(m_bAutoClose ? m_nAutoCloseTime * 1000 : 0);
    CPoint m_ptPopup = CPoint(-1, -1);
    pPopup->Create(ts->_this, IDD_ALERT_JOB, NULL, m_ptPopup, 
    RUNTIME_CLASS(JobAlertDlg));
    pPopup->SetWindowText(_T("Message"));
    //cout << string(buf, 0, bytesReceived) << endl;

    // Echo message back to client
    send(clientSocket, "OK", bytesReceived + 1, 0);
}

// Close the socket
closesocket(clientSocket);

// Cleanup winsock
WSACleanup();
return 0;
}

BOOL JobManager::OnInitDialog()
{
  THREADSTRUCT *_param = new THREADSTRUCT;
  _param->_this = this;
  CWinThread *ptrThread = AfxBeginThread(JobInfoAlert, _param)
  CDialog::OnInitDialog();
  return true;
}
```

Comment: A thread that wishes to display a UI must dispatch messages on that thread. The code presented here does not. When using raw sockets, dispatching messages during blocking calls is on the developer. Use [`CSocket`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/csocket-class) instead for an implementation that handles this for you.

Answer (score -1):

You are creating the alert dialog in the context of the worker thread, and this means that the window will be owned by that thread, while its parent (`JobManager` dialog) will be (presumably) owned by the UI (main) thread. This is a setup to be avoided. Also, the worker thread, is created by the overloaded version of the `AfxBeginThread()` function which doesn't create a message-queue, and this means that it won't be processing the (alert) window's messages.

Since you have decided to create a worker thread for handling the sockets communication, it would be best to separate the background from the UI operations - they can communicate asynchronously. A quite easy way to do this is to define a custom message (`WM_APP+nnnn`) and an `ON_MESSAGE()` handler in the dialog class. The worker thread will be posting these messages to the dialog window. You can pass information in the `wParam` and `lParam` parameters, typically (but not necessarily) `wParam` contains data like integers, enums, codes etc while `lParam` larger items (often a pointer), although under x64 they are both 64-bit. The notification codes can be placed in `wParam`, for example - you can define the message and its parameters the way you wish.

Therefore you should move the code creating the alert dialog out of the thread function, eg in the aforementioned message handler. This would create the alert dialog in the context of the UI thread, so it will be owned by the UI thread. Your code needs some more improvements, in the cases of failure, disconnecting etc for example, the worker thread displays a message box and terminates, while the `JobManager` dialog seemingly receives no notification. You should rather put such information in the custom message (processed by the handler), so the dialog class can take actions accordingly, eg enable/disable controls or close.

Minor memory leak, the worker thread before exiting should release the memory allocated for `THREADSTRUCT` in `OnInitDialog()`, you just allocate it and pass it to the thread. Or you could avoid allocating/freeing it at all, you seem to use only the `_this` member, so you could pass it directly as the `LPVOID` parameter.